# ¿Cómo crear una dataframe con los resultados de un diccionario en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base-de-datos, pandas

Estoy experimentado con lo siguiente:

```
a="Mi perro come mi perro come hola si"

dicto={}
for i in a.lower().split():
    if i not in dicto:
        dicto[i]=1
    else:
        dicto[i]+=1

dicto


#Salida:

 {'mi': 2, 'perro': 2, 'come': 2, 'hola': 1, 'si': 1}
```

Ahora bien, quiero crear una dataframe con estos resultados y para ello utilizo pandas

```
import pandas as pd
db=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicto, orient="index")
db


#Salida
       0
mi     2
perro  2
come   2
hola   1
si     1
```

Lo que quiero ahora es que las palabras y los valores asociados sean variables por si solas. Sin embargo, entiendo que la salida que da la función `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` utiliza las palabras como `rownames` y no encuentro ninguna forma de hacerlo como deseo, es decir, algo como:

```
Palabra    Frecuencia
mi            2
perro         2
come          2
hola          1
si            1
```

Revisé la ayuda para la función y diversas publicaciones tanto aquí como en SO en inglés sin éxito alguno, así que cualquier comentario lo agradeceré mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente Alejandro, las claves del diccionario son consideradas como un índice del `data.frame`, exactamente son `rownames` de R. Sin embargo puedes convertir las mismas en una columna estándar mediante [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
db=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicto, orient="index").reset_index()
db.columns = ['Palabra', 'Frecuencia'] # Renombramos las columnas a nuestro gusto
print(db)

  Palabra  Frecuencia
0      mi           2
1   perro           2
2    come           2
3    hola           1
4      si           1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, como siempre. Eres el mejor :D